# printing a dictionary with specific format

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

i am already done with my project and i want to print my results.
i have a dictionary like this:
`{('a',): 4, ('b',): 5, ('c', 'd'): 3, ('e', 'f'): 4, ('g', 'h'): 3, ('i',): 3}`

the key in some pair key-value is one element and in some others is two or three.
and i want to print it in this format, the elements with one key in one line, the elements with two keys in a new line etc...

```
(elem,)
(elem1, elem2, ..., elem_n)
```

i tried this:

```
itemdct //my dict
result = [itemdct]
csv_writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter=';')
row = []
for itemdct in result:
    for key in sorted(itemdct.keys()):
        row.append("{0}:{1}".format(key, itemdct[key]))
csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

but my output is like this in one line.

```
('a',):3;('b',):4;('c', 'd'):3;('e', 'f'):3;......
```

mydict is like this

```
{('a',): 3, ('b', 'c'): 3, ....}
```

and the result is like this

```
[{('a',): 3, ('b', 'c'): 3,.....}]
```

thank you in advance..

edit: i want my output to be like this:

```
('a',):3;('c',):4;('c',):5;('d',):6;('e',):3
('a', 'c'):3;('b', 'd'):3;('c', 'd'):4
```

Comment: So given your example input - what *exactly* is the required output?

Comment: Can you [edit] that into your question - so it's probably formatted :)

Comment: Can you explain where the line breaks should be? Every 4 rows? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: the line breaks is not fixed, the first line should have all the elements with one key `('a',)`, the second line should have the elements with two keys `('a','b')`

Comment: Uh tuple keys aren't a good format for a dictionary, but what you probably want is `sorted(d.items(), key=lambda k: len(k))`, then an if statement to print `\n` in the loop or a bisect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the items of your dictionary according to their key length. The you can use groupby to group by key length and print each group.

```
def printDict(myDict):
    from itertools import groupby
    def sortFunc(item):
        return len(item[0])

    sortedItems = sorted(myDict.items(), key=sortFunc)
    groups = groupby(sortedItems, sortFunc)
    for _, group in groups:         
        print( ';'.join('%s:%s' % entry for entry in group))
```

Output:

```
>>> printDict({('a',): 4, ('b',): 5, ('c', 'd'): 3, ('e', 'f'): 4, ('g', 'h'): 3, ('i',): 3})
('a',):4;('i',):3;('b',):5
('e', 'f'):4;('g', 'h'):3;('c', 'd'):3
```

Comment: Guess the downvote was for not being pythonic... it should be now :D

Comment: I unchecked it and posted a solution w/ `groupby` instead  - although I guess your answer is basically the same now ;p

Comment: @user3467349 yeah I wasn't quite satisfied with my answer either...  then groupby came to my mind :D

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools.groupby` (one thing to note is that you have to sort first, because [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) will create a new group when the key value changes):

```
from itertools import groupby
d = {('a',): 4, ('b',): 5, ('c', 'd'): 3, ('e', 'f'): 4, ('g', 'h'): 3, ('i',): 3}
for i, g in groupby(sorted(d.items(), key = lambda k: len(k[0])), lambda k: len(k[0])):
  print(';'.join('%s:%s' %(k,v) for k,v in g))

## -- End pasted text --
('a',):4;('i',):3;('b',):5
('e', 'f'):4;('g', 'h'):3;('c', 'd'):3
```

p.s. I'm not sure what your assignment is, but you should probably not be using tuples as keys in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

There is two steps to this. The first is to sort out what entry goes into what line, the other is to print those lines.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = {('a',): 4, ('b',): 5, ('c', 'd'): 3, ('e', 'f'): 4, ('g', 'h'): 3, ('i',): 3}

keysize = defaultdict(list)
for key in d:
    keysize[len(key)].append("{}:{}".format(key, h[key]))

for size, line in keysize.iteritems():
    print ", ".join(line)
```